# Converting pandas panel object to rpy2.robjects.vectors.Array object

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

Is there a function to convert pandas panel (3-dimensional) object to a `rpy2.Array` object?

I was able to do this to convert only the data to `rpy2.Array`. But this doesnt set the dimnames/names for the array object.

```
arrayobj = rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.numpy2ri(panelobj.values)
```

Is there a clean way of converting the panel to `rpy2.Array`?

Comment: Your post suggests that this use-case is not yet well covered. If you can cook up a simple self-contained example (one can just copy paste to trigger the problem), I believe that a fix can be proposed here fairly quickly, and that fix be pushed in the code base of rpy2 within a short additional time.

Comment: FYI, you can change a panel to a frame, ``panel.to_frame()`` which creates a multi-index frame that I believe you can then directly export (to a data.frame)